# Interpreting FURA depolarization/calcium assay

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology

I did a depolarization experiment that compared a mock-treated cell line with a treated line. One part of the results are easy to interpret: Treatment resulted in lower 350/380 ratios along the length of the response curve. That's easy, the treatment probably reduced calcium transport. However, in addition to this, the treatment also significantly shifted each inflection in the curve earlier in number of cycles. How could this be interpreted?

Comment: You'll need to explain more what your experiment procedure is for this to be answerable.

Comment: I concur With Bryan - more experimental details are needed. If in any way possible, a graphical representation of the results would be great. A hand-drawn plot can already help a lot if you don't wish to make your source data public.